# VBA Error Using ProtectSheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ProtectAll()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim ShPwd As String
ShPwd = "123456789"
CurPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
CurFilename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
CurFile = CurPath & "\" & CurFilename
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
wSheet.Protect Password:=ShPwd, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True,          Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
Next wSheet
ActiveWorkbook.Protect (Pwd)
ActiveWorkbook.ProtectSharing Filename:=CurFile, SharingPassword:=ShPwd
End Sub
```

So I am getting an error on the final line with the sharingpassword it seems, what am I doing wrong on that line. when I run the macro I get an error of run time error 5 invalid call or argument.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may only be able to either Protect **OR** ProtectSharing a single workbook, not both.  Try deleting/commenting-out the line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect (Pwd)
```

(or of course the `ActiveWorkbook.ProtectSharing ...` line).

This worked for me in a simple test.